# Are we obliged (have responsibility) to think/act rationaly?

Tags: rationality

A person who leads a very organized daily life from morning to night might not be much happier from a person who has no routine at all and do whatever he likes, whenever he wants. Similarly it can be argued in numerous spheres of life that, our lives will have almost no positive changes (predominantly from materialistic point of view), even if we don't act in a rational (just) way? Do we have a responsibility like moral responsibility to act in a rational/logical way. And who will decide whether my actions are logical or not? Definitly not through head count as we can think of a society where irrational (like brutal) acts can have majority consent (like ISIS bandits).

Comment: How do you define the acts of ISIS as "irrational?"  Is this a personal bias?  Interestingly, in Rational Choice Theory, "rational" is explicitly defined to solve this: " At its most basic level, behavior is rational if it is goal-oriented, reflective (evaluative), and consistent (across time and different choice situations). This contrasts with behavior that is random, impulsive, conditioned, or adopted by (unevaluative) imitation."  Quite often what we mean by irrational is "irrational if we assume the axioms I assume to be true."

Comment: I'm curious at to why you think that ISIS has majority consent? They strike me as being the most effective in *enforcing* majority consent by their use of political violence ...

Comment: @MoziburUllah I don't want to start pure political discussion here. What I meant here were those few thousand indoctrinated youth who traveled from across the world for this purpose. If you take these thousands of people, then majority of them will agree on what they are doing. I am not talking about the masses whom they are controlling/governing. I will not wish that ISIS thing divert the discussion away from actual question.

Comment: @Ather Cheema: Its good that you clarified, as I was taking it in the second sense; but I should point out thats the usual notion of a *majority*; I mean if you're carefully choosing a group by a criteria, then by that criteria they automatically form a majority!